# Remove duplicates from an unsorted Linked List in Ruby

Tags: algorithm, ruby, linked-list, memory-management

Currently I'm going over the cracking the coding interview. I'm in the **Linked List 2.1** question which is as follow:

> Remove Duplicates, write code to remove duplicates from an unsorted
>   Linked List. How would you solve the problem if a temporary buffer is
>   not allowed?

I used a Hash, which breaks the *temporary buffer not allowed* conditioned. Not sure how one can go about solving this without using an extra data structure. The above is the method I used.

```
# CTCI-2.1: Write code to remove duplicates from an unsorted LinkedList
  def remove_duplicates
    node = @head
    h = Hash.new(0)
    return false unless node.next
    h[@head.data] += 1
    while (node = node.next)
      h[node.data] += 1
      if h[node.data] > 1
        previous_node = find_previous(node.data)
        previous_node.next = previous_node.next.next
      end
    end
  end
```

This is a \$O(n)\$. How can this be improved? How one will go about solving this without using an additional data structure(Temporary buffer?) Here is the rest of the Linked List:
require 'pry'

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :next
  attr_reader :data

  def initialize(data)
    @data = data
    @next = nil
  end

  def to_s
    "Node with value: #{data}"
  end
end

class LinkedList
  def initialize
    @head = nil
  end

  def append(value)
    if @head
      find_tale.next = Node.new(value)
    else
      @head = Node.new(value)
    end
  end

  def find_tale
    node = @head

    return node if !node.next
    return node if !node.next while (node = node.next)
  end

  def find(value)
    node = @head 

    return false if !node.next
    return node if node.data == value 

    while (node = node.next)
      return node if node.data == value
    end
  end

  def append_after(target, value)
    node = find(target)
    return unless node

    old_next = node.next
    node.next = Node.new(value)
    node.next.next = old_next
  end

  def find_previous(value)
    node = @head 

    return false if !node.next
    return node if node.next.data == value 

    while(node = node.next)
      return node if node.next.data == value
    end
  end

  def delete(value)
    if @head.data == value
      @head = @head.next
    end

    node = find_previous(value)
    node.next = node.next.next
  end

  def display
    node = @head

    puts node
    while (node = node.next)
      puts node
    end
  end

  # CTCI-2.1: Write code to remove duplicates from an unsorted LinkedList
  def remove_duplicates
    node = @head
    h = Hash.new(0)
    return false unless node.next
    h[@head.data] += 1
    while (node = node.next)
      h[node.data] += 1
      if h[node.data] > 1
        previous_node = find_previous(node.data)
        previous_node.next = previous_node.next.next
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the test I used:

```
# TEST 
list = LinkedList.new

list.append('A')
list.append('B')
list.append('A')
list.append('A')
list.append('C')
list.append('D')


puts "Display the list"

list.display

list.remove_duplicates
puts 'Answer should be A B C D'
list.display
```

Comment: A minor thing, I would write `previous_node.next = previous_node.next.next` as `previous_node.next = node.next`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Alternatives

There are [other alternatives (spoiler alert)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-duplicates-from-an-unsorted-linked-list/) with around the same time complexity, that adhere to the specification of in-place removal.

---

### Review

> This is in \$O(n)\$.

I'm not sure it is. The outer iteration `while (node = node.next)` is \$O(n)\$.

> ```
> while (node = node.next)
>   h[node.data] += 1
>   if h[node.data] > 1
>     previous_node = find_previous(node.data)
>     previous_node.next = previous_node.next.next
>   end
> end
> ```

And `find_previous(data)` is \$O(\log{n})\$.

> ```
>  def find_previous(value)
>     node = @head 
>
>     return false if !node.next
>     return node if node.next.data == value 
>
>     while(node = node.next)
>       return node if node.next.data == value
>     end   
>  end
> ```

This makes `remove_duplicates` to be \$O(n\log{n})\$.

If you keep track of the previous node while iterating the nodes, you could optimize your algorithm to be \$O(n)\$, but as you are using a hash table, it fails to meet the requirements of the challenge.

---

Comment: As you point out `find_previous` is a relatively expensive operation. I would add another  local variable to track the previous node. i.e at the top of the function add `previous = @head` and at the end of the loop `previous = node`

Comment: Looking at that, you should only update `previous` if you didn't delete the node.

Comment: @MarcRohloff that's how I would do it as well. But I'll leave it up to OP to come up with a similar solution :)

Comment: would using merge sort violate the no extra buffer condition? I think merge sort uses two arrays but not sure if their created in memory

Comment: I believe it would breach that condition: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/.